# How to run some code in background fetch in Suspended?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push

How can i run some code then i got "Push notification"? in Objective c.

Then my app is running i got push notification, but then my app is closed i got nothing. but not push notification in Suspended), but can't run some code

Here is my code.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {}
```

But nothing happen!

All what i want is run some code in background fetch in (Suspended)!

Comment: Is your app suspended or terminated? Did you send a push with `content-available: 1` ?  What do you expect to happen?  You have no code to execute.

Comment: Yes i got "content-available: 1", in my payload in firebase push

Comment: i expect, i can urn some code, push back to my mdm server

Comment: But you haven't shown any code, just an empty method declaration. Also, are you sure your app is suspended and not terminated?  Have you set a breakpoint in the method and your app is running under the Xcode debugger when you send your push

Comment: When my iPhone gets a specific push notification, how can this push notification trigger to start a suspended application in my iPhone? I have tried "content-available: 1" in my payload. It will not wake my application up!